# Android Service: detect if startService or startForegroundService was used

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

On Android 9 and 10, how can I distinguish if my Service was invoked via `startService` or via `startForegroundService`? Is there some way in `onStartCommand` function inside Service?

Basically, I would like to discard foreground requests with an *Error*, and only process background ones. The requests are comming from a 3rd party app, which I do not have under my controll.